# Add unique elements in HashSet based on attributes of framework provided non-editable object classes

Tags: java, collections, equals, hashset, hashcode

I am trying to generate a `HashSet` containing unique `Employee` instances. Uniqueness should be established based on the object properties.

The problem is that I end up with having duplicates.

**Note** that `Employee` class is provided by a framework, and it's **not possible** to provide custom implementations for `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

*`Employee` class:*

```
public class Employee {
    private long employeeId;
    private String name;

    // getters, setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "employeeId=" + employeeId +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
Map<String, Set<Employee>> ackErrorMap = new HashMap<>();

Employee emp = new Employee(1,"bon");
Employee emp2 = new Employee(1,"bon");

ackErrorMap.computeIfAbsent("key1",
    x -> new HashSet<>()).add(emp);

ackErrorMap.computeIfAbsent("key1",
    x -> new HashSet<>()).add(emp2);
```

This would result in a Set mapped to the Key `"key1"` containing both `emp` and `emp2`, although object attributes are same.

Is there any way to discard `Employee` with the same `name`? Or would it better to use `ArrayList`?

Possible example using `Arraylist`

```
ackErrorMap.computeIfAbsent("key1",
    x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(emp);
```

Comment: Does `Employee` have any sensible implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`? If it's the default implementations provided by `Object` different instances will be considered non-equal no matter the values.

Comment: Actually, in this case the Employee class is provided by a framework and it would not be possible to provide custom implementations to equals() and hashcode().

Comment: Well, in that case you might need to provide a wrapper class that implements those methods, i.e. you'd then get a `Map<String, Set<EmployeeWrapper>>`.

Comment: @alexander-ivanchenko Edited question with class structure and other information.

Comment: Why do you think, using `ArrayList` could be a solution? In what regard do you expect it to be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom type wrapping the class coming from the framework and implement the `equals/hashCode` contract according to your requirements.

That's how such wrapper might look like (for the purpose of conciseness I'm using a [Java 16 `record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/records.html), but it can be implemented as a `class` as well).

```
public record EmployeeWrapper(Employee employee) {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof EmployeeWrapper other
            && employee.getName().equals(other.employee.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(employee.getName());
    }
}
```

And you can use with a Map of type `Map<String,Set<EmployeeWrapper>>` to ensure uniqueness of the `Employee` based on the `name` property.

I would also advise to make one step further and encapsulate the Map into a `class` which would expose the methods covering all scenarios of interaction with the Map (like add new entry, get employees by key, etc.), so that your client would not dial wrappers, but only with employees and wrapping and unwrapping would happen within the enclosing class.

Here's how it might be implemented:

```
public class AcrErrors {
    private Map<String, Set<EmployeeWrapper>> ackErrorMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void addEmployee(String key, Employee employee) {
        EmployeeWrapper wrapper = new EmployeeWrapper(employee);
        
        ackErrorMap
            .computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new HashSet<>())
            .add(wrapper);
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(String key) {
        
        return ackErrorMap.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptySet()).stream()
            .map(EmployeeWrapper::employee)
            .toList();
    }
    
    // other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals() and hashCode() inside Employee class.
Or you can use lombok’s @EqualsAndHashCode annotation in your Employee class.